# Why am I receiving extra responses when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a small "quiz" game (just for the sake of learning). The "big picture" of what I am trying to do is determine whether or not the end-user has selected the right answer based on what index value the "gameBegin" array.

It is currently giving me the answer "correct" for selecting the correct radio button on the first question and then on the next question, when I select that same radio button, it will say "correct" and "wrong." On the third question if I select that same radio button, it will say "correct," "wrong," and "wrong" etc.

**Edit: This is actually a response but I don't like the way my comment got formatted (I thought it was harder to read for people reading this thread), so I just edited my post.**

> "As each question loads, it's adding more click handlers to the
>   answerChoices"

Do you know why more click handlers are added to the "answerChoices" as each question loads? In my mind,it checks to see if "gameBeginValue" equals a certain value, runs a function if it does, and then moves on to check and see if it equals another value and runs that function if it doesn't.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <section class="headingIntroduction">
        <div class="headingTitle">
            <h2>Welcome to the Halloween Quiz Game!</h2>
            <hr/>
            <!--The paragraph tag directly below this
            is left blank because when the game starts, I want
            it to be blank. I only want it to have content on one 
            particular part of the program only.
            -->
            <p></p>
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="formInput">
            <form>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice0" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice0"/><span></span>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice1" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice1"/><span></span>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice2" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice2"/><span></span>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice3" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice3"/><span></span>
                <hr/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="submitButton">
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Click Here to Begin!"/>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="userScore">
            <h3>Score:</h3>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/*
    When the page loads, I only want the welcome page to show. I want
    everything else to be hidden. Also want answer choices to remain hidden.
*/

$('form').hide()

var gameBegin = [
{/*Instructions Page*/
    question: 'Welcome to the Game Instructions Page!',
    instructions:'  You will be presented with several questions. Below each question are a set of answers. Select the answer that you think is correct and then click the "Submit" button to see if your answer is correct. At the end of the game, you will see your final score to let you know how you did.Choose carefully! Once you move onto the next question, you cannot go back!',
    choice: '',
    correctAnswer: '',
    buttonValue: 'Start Game!'
},
{/*question One*/
    question: 'What Film Series is Freddy Krueger From?',
    instructions: 'Question 1 out of 5',
    choice: ['A Nightmare on Elm Street', 'Simpsons Treehouse of Horror', '28 Days Later', 'The Texas Chainsaw Massacre'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Two*/
    question: 'Which Terrifying Villian Uses a Chainsaw to Murder His Victims?',
    instructions: 'Question 2 out of 5',
    choice: ['Jason Voorhees', 'Dracula', 'Frankenstein', 'Leatherface'],
    correctAnswer: 3,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Three*/
    question: 'What is the Occupation of Sweeney Todd?',
    instructions: 'Question 3 out of 5',
    choice: ['Teacher', 'Priest', 'Barber', 'Doctor'],
    correctAnswer: 2,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Four*/
    question: 'Who are the villians in the 1993 film "Hocus Pocus?"',
    instructions: 'Question 4 out of 5',
    choice: ['The Sanderson Sisters', 'Vlad the Impaler', 'Jigsaw', 'The Blair Witch'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Five*/
    question: 'Which Serial Killer is Leatherface Based On?',
    instructions: 'Question 5 out of 5',
    choice: ['Ted Bundy', 'Ed Gein', 'Charles Manson', 'Jack the Ripper'],
    correctAnswer: 1,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Game Finished Screen*/
    question: 'Congratulations! You Finished The Halloween Quiz Game!',
    instructions: 'To play again, click the button below.',
    choice: '',
    correctAnswer: '',
    buttonValue: 'Start New Game'
}
]

/*global variables*/

var gameBeginValue = 0;
var zero = "answerChoice0";
var one = "answerChoice1";
var two = "answerChoice2";
var three = "answerChoice3";


/*Moving from Page to Page When Clicking Submit Button*/

$('#submitButton').on('click',function(){



    /*I want the gameBeginValue to reset back to 0 to start a new game
    There is no need to reshow the welcome page again. I also want
    the radio buttons to only appear if the user is looking at a 
    question. */

    if(gameBeginValue > 6){
        gameBeginValue = 0;
    } else if ((gameBeginValue < 1) || (gameBeginValue > 5)) {
        $('form').hide();
    }else{
        $('form').show();
    }


    /*Heading at top of Page*/
    var questionTitle = $('h2');
    questionTitle[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].question;

    /*The information section for playing the game*/
    var gameInformation = $('p');
    gameInformation[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].instructions;

    /*Changing the values of the input choices based on question.*/
    var questionChoice =$('span');
    questionChoice[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[0];
    questionChoice[1].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[1];
    questionChoice[2].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[2];
    questionChoice[3].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[3];

    /*Changing the value of the submit button based on what screen you are on */
    var buttonDescription = $("#submitButton");
    buttonDescription[0].value = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].buttonValue;

    /*-----------------------------------------*/
    if (gameBeginValue==1){
        question1();
    }else if (gameBeginValue==2){
        question2();
    }else{

    }

    /*I want the gameBeginValue variable to increase everytime this button is clicked
    But I want it to Happen Last.*/
    $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', false);

    gameBeginValue++;

    /*I want the radio buttons to all be unchecked at the start of the
    next question*/
    $('#answerChoice0').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice1').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice2').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice3').prop('checked',false);

    /*I want a message to appear to let you know if the answer you chose
    was correct or not*/



})

function question1(){
    $('#answerChoice0').on('click',function(){
        alert('correct!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}

function question2(){
    $('#answerChoice0').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').on('click',function(){
        alert('correct');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}


})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each question loads, it's adding more click handlers to the `answerChoice`s. So as the user clicks radio buttons on the second question, there are 2 handlers fired, on the third there are 3, and so on.

You need to uniquely identify each question's radio buttons, or *replace* the handlers. The second option is the quicker for you at this point, but I'd encourage trying to refactor your design to avoid needing unique functions for each question. Anyway - to remove previous click handlers, use the jQuery [`.off()` method](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

For example:

```
function question1(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('correct!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}
```

You can try this out with the code snippet below, or with [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k270xe4j/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

/*
    When the page loads, I only want the welcome page to show. I want
    everything else to be hidden. Also want answer choices to remain hidden.
*/

$('form').hide()

var gameBegin = [
{/*Instructions Page*/
    question: 'Welcome to the Game Instructions Page!',
    instructions:'  You will be presented with several questions. Below each question are a set of answers. Select the answer that you think is correct and then click the "Submit" button to see if your answer is correct. At the end of the game, you will see your final score to let you know how you did.Choose carefully! Once you move onto the next question, you cannot go back!',
    choice: '',
    correctAnswer: '',
    buttonValue: 'Start Game!'
},
{/*question One*/
    question: 'What Film Series is Freddy Krueger From?',
    instructions: 'Question 1 out of 5',
    choice: ['A Nightmare on Elm Street', 'Simpsons Treehouse of Horror', '28 Days Later', 'The Texas Chainsaw Massacre'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Two*/
    question: 'Which Terrifying Villian Uses a Chainsaw to Murder His Victims?',
    instructions: 'Question 2 out of 5',
    choice: ['Jason Voorhees', 'Dracula', 'Frankenstein', 'Leatherface'],
    correctAnswer: 3,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Three*/
    question: 'What is the Occupation of Sweeney Todd?',
    instructions: 'Question 3 out of 5',
    choice: ['Teacher', 'Priest', 'Barber', 'Doctor'],
    correctAnswer: 2,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Four*/
    question: 'Who are the villians in the 1993 film "Hocus Pocus?"',
    instructions: 'Question 4 out of 5',
    choice: ['The Sanderson Sisters', 'Vlad the Impaler', 'Jigsaw', 'The Blair Witch'],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Question Five*/
    question: 'Which Serial Killer is Leatherface Based On?',
    instructions: 'Question 5 out of 5',
    choice: ['Ted Bundy', 'Ed Gein', 'Charles Manson', 'Jack the Ripper'],
    correctAnswer: 1,
    buttonValue: 'Submit Answer'
},
{/*Game Finished Screen*/
    question: 'Congratulations! You Finished The Halloween Quiz Game!',
    instructions: 'To play again, click the button below.',
    choice: '',
    correctAnswer: '',
    buttonValue: 'Start New Game'
}
]

/*global variables*/

var gameBeginValue = 0;
var zero = "answerChoice0";
var one = "answerChoice1";
var two = "answerChoice2";
var three = "answerChoice3";


/*Moving from Page to Page When Clicking Submit Button*/

$('#submitButton').on('click',function(){



    /*I want the gameBeginValue to reset back to 0 to start a new game
    There is no need to reshow the welcome page again. I also want
    the radio buttons to only appear if the user is looking at a 
    question. */

    if(gameBeginValue > 6){
        gameBeginValue = 0;
    } else if ((gameBeginValue < 1) || (gameBeginValue > 5)) {
        $('form').hide();
    }else{
        $('form').show();
    }


    /*Heading at top of Page*/
    var questionTitle = $('h2');
    questionTitle[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].question;

    /*The information section for playing the game*/
    var gameInformation = $('p');
    gameInformation[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].instructions;

    /*Changing the values of the input choices based on question.*/
    var questionChoice =$('span');
    questionChoice[0].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[0];
    questionChoice[1].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[1];
    questionChoice[2].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[2];
    questionChoice[3].textContent = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].choice[3];

    /*Changing the value of the submit button based on what screen you are on */
    var buttonDescription = $("#submitButton");
    buttonDescription[0].value = gameBegin[gameBeginValue].buttonValue;

    /*-----------------------------------------*/
    if (gameBeginValue==1){
        question1();
    }else if (gameBeginValue==2){
        question2();
    }else{

    }

    /*I want the gameBeginValue variable to increase everytime this button is clicked
    But I want it to Happen Last.*/
    $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', false);

    gameBeginValue++;

    /*I want the radio buttons to all be unchecked at the start of the
    next question*/
    $('#answerChoice0').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice1').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice2').prop('checked',false);
    $('#answerChoice3').prop('checked',false);

    /*I want a message to appear to let you know if the answer you chose
    was correct or not*/



})

function question1(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('correct!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}

function question2(){
    $('#answerChoice0').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong!');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice1').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice2').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('correct');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);
    })
    $('#answerChoice3').off('click').on('click',function(){
        alert('wrong');
        $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', true);

    })
}


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <section class="headingIntroduction">
        <div class="headingTitle">
            <h2>Welcome to the Halloween Quiz Game!</h2>
            <hr/>
            <!--The paragraph tag directly below this
            is left blank because when the game starts, I want
            it to be blank. I only want it to have content on one 
            particular part of the program only.
            -->
            <p></p>
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="formInput">
            <form>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice0" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice0"/><span></span>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice1" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice1"/><span></span>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice2" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice2"/><span></span>
                <input type="radio" id="answerChoice3" name="answerChoice" value="answerChoice3"/><span></span>
                <hr/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="submitButton">
            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Click Here to Begin!"/>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="userScore">
            <h3>Score:</h3>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: When you say "Uniquely Identify" do you mean change the name value or the id value? I am going to assume name value. The reason that I have the same name value is to stop end-users from selecting more than 1 radio button.

Comment: Various approaches would work, such as arrays of elements or IDs made up of concatenated digits, etc.

Comment: I just did some research on the off() method that you suggested (I didn't even know this existed because I'm still new at this), is there any advantage in using off() vs one()?

Comment: `one()` will only work once, then is automatically unbound. If your design would have had you calling `off()` in the handler itself, use `one()` instead. But if you want to allow for an element to be clicked multiple times, `one()` is inappropriate.